# Use of "a good laugh"

Tags: expressions

Commenting a statement, I want to convey the idea that besides the fact that this statement has the virtue of making us laugh, it is also instructive for such and such reason. Can I use any of the following sentences?

"John said this and that, which, **besides being a good laugh**, also showed this"

"John said this and that, which, **besides providing a good laugh**, also showed this"

"John said this and that, which, **besides offering a good laugh**, also showed this"

"John said this and that, which, **besides giving us a good laugh**, also showed this"

Comment: The fourth one sounds the most natural to these old British ears. The others, lacking '*us*', only work if you are certain that what he says will make the *reader* laugh as well as you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing is the 'us' in the fourth one, in the way I intended to use it, actually referred to "the readers and myself" and not to "some other people and myself at the time John made this statement." It will be understood this way since I was not there when John made the statement. I actually want to insist that what John said is something to be laughed at. Would you still say that the fourth option is correct?

Comment: @Mike: Ah. Well explained! In that case I would say, *John said this and that, which - as well as being funny - showed this.* (You don't need "also".) I wouldn't describe any of the four, or my rewrite, as **correct** though: the tone is informal and there's no *correct* in informal English. The words "as well as" are maybe a tad more colloquial  and consistent with the informality than "besides". So are the hyphens. But it's only my own feeling. You *could* stick with "a good laugh", but whatever he said had better be funny!

Comment: Thanks for these detailed and clear answers. I fear "funny" won't be strong enough. But yes, what John said was funny!

Comment: @Mike: Good! In that case, "- as well as being a good laugh -".